# Print items in list to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so i have a code like this :

```
hehe = 'ip.txt'

def ip(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as list :
        lists = list.read().splitlines()
        
        ips = '\n'.join(map(str, lists))
        for ip in ips:
            ip1 = ip.rstrip('\n') 
            return ip1


list = ip(hehe)
print(list)
```

i have file of ips like :

- 1.1.1.1
- 2.2.2.2
- 3.3.3.3

I want to get every ip and scan it in next function / basiclly in reverse ip tool

when I execute my code I get only the last one !! my brain is dead today any help?

Comment: `return ip1` ends the function, so the loop stops. You only get the first IP, not the last.

Comment: `ips` is not a list, why are you looping over it?

Comment: The whole thing could be `return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in list]`

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a Python built-in.

Comment: if i use return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in list] i will get a list instead if ips as variables !!

Comment: What is your expected output @yxxhixx

Comment: You don't need it as variables.

Comment: my expected output is ips not list brother , to put them into another function

Comment: You can technically do that by indexing the list. You want variables named ip1, ip2, ip3, ...? A dictionary looks better for you then.

Comment: If you get a list of IPs, you can then loop over that list in the next function.

Comment: Also, `splitlines()` removes the newlines, you don't need to call `rstrip()`. You can just do `return list.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the IPs stored in variables `ip1`, `ip2`, and so on, that is bad practice particularly when the number of IPs is large.

You are better off storing them in a dictionary (a container of `key: value` pairs) whereby the keys are `'ip1'`, `'ip2'`, and so on, and the values are the corresponding IPs.

However, `ip1`, `ip2` and so on is not very meaningful. It is basically just the index of the IP in the file plus one. So a list is also well-suited for your problem.

The following shows how you might use a `dict` or `list`. We create the function `myprint` just to illustrate passing the dictionary, the list, or individual elements from the dictionary or list to a function.

With a dictionary, say, `a`, `a['ip1']` is your first IP, `a['ip2']` is your second IP, and so on.

With a list, say, `b`, `b[0]` is your first IP (ip1), `b[1]` is your second IP (ip2), and so on.

By the way, given the simplicity of the functions, you can simply forget about defining them and assign the expression in the return statement directly to a variable (with the assignment occurring in some `with` statement suite). However, I have included the functions to better match the code in your question.

```
def ip2_dict(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return {f"ip{idx+1}":line.rstrip() for idx, line in enumerate(f)}

def ip2_list(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return [line.rstrip() for line in f]

def myprint(s):
    print(s)

a = ip2_dict('ip.txt')
b = ip2_list('ip.txt')

# print dictionary of IPs
myprint(a)
# print list of IPs
myprint(b)
# print specific IP from dict
myprint(a['ip1'])
# print specific IP from list
myprint(b[0])
```

Output

```
{'ip1': '1.1.1.1', 'ip2': '2.2.2.2', 'ip3': '3.3.3.3'}
['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
```